# Make bootstrap nav in mobile, expanding from left side instead of dropping down.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

More of a backend guy, just looking for some direction on customizing bootstrap in XS to basically act like the amazon phone app.

I want the nav expand menu button to have the nav pop out from the left instead of dropping down. Is there a good way to do this in bootstrap, or is it best to just write something custom? If custom is best, would it be best to try and override the data-target/data-toggle or just do a js onClick and run my code?

There will also be expandable sub menu's/drop down menus like Amazons instant video and apps, is that something best written custom or is there a good way to do it in bootstrap? I know the drop downs in bootstrap, but not really seeing how to  expand a menu option.

Thanx ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of using Bootstrap components with custom code and jQuerys toggleClass to initiate the mobile off-canvas menu. If you're going to use a Framework you should use as much built in functionality as possible which I think this example does: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elektriheart/ctykz3xa/)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button data-toggle="collapse-side" data-target=".side-collapse" data-target-2=".side-collapse-container" type="button" class="navbar-toggle"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-default side-collapse in">
            <nav role="navigation" class="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> 
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a> 
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a> 
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a> 
                            </li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a> 
                            </li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a> 
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a> 
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a> 
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a> 
                            </li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a> 
                            </li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a> 
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="side-collapse-container">
        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

            </button> <strong>Warning!</strong> This is an Off-Canvas Mobile Menu</div>
    </div>
</div>
```